# Visual Studio 2013 Express - How do I add resources?

Tags: c++, resources, visual-studio-2013, sfml

I'm currently linking to the >dynamic< libs in SFML but I have no idea how to add resources in Visual Studio 2013 Express C++. I've quite recently started out with C++, coming from C# where adding resources is as simple as drag-n-drop.

I know there's something with .rc files and headers, but I didn't find any guide on it. What I need to do is add the dll's so I don't have to manually paste them with the .exe and I also need to add .png's. Right now I'm loading them from a folder next to the executable, I don't wanna do that.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add an [.rc] file to the project.

An [.rc] file is a purely textual **resource script** that you can edit as text, or you can use various 3<sup>rd</sup> party resource editors (you don't need that for adding image resources, just check out the [RC syntax](https://www.google.com/search?q=rc+syntax)).

Visual Studio Express lacks resource *editors*, but does support automatic recognition of, compilation of and linking of resources.

---

**Example**

Here's an example [.rc] file, just a single line, using a free icon that I just downloaded from the net:

```
100 ICON "resources\\Bad-Blood-Yolks-Grin.ico"
```

Corresponding C++ source code, presenting the icon in a message box:

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

auto main() -> int
{
    MSGBOXPARAMS params = {sizeof( params )};
    params.hInstance        = GetModuleHandle( nullptr );
    params.lpszText         = L"Click OK to dismiss this box.";
    params.lpszCaption      = L"Καλὴ τύχη!";        // "Good luck!" in Greek.
    params.dwStyle          = MB_USERICON;
    params.lpszIcon         = MAKEINTRESOURCE( 100 );

    MessageBoxIndirect( &params );
}
```

Result:

[image]

All done in Visual C++ Express for Desktop 2013, or whatever it calls itself. :-)

In order to synchronize identifiers between resource script and C or C++ code it's common to include a header. The resource compiler understands the most basic C preprocessor directives.

Oh, also, I added the [.rc] file as just a text file. Visual Studio Express reacts to the renaming, "rc" file extension, by popping up a warning box that it isn't supported. Just ignore the box, and to edit the file right-click and choose text editor.

Comment: I'm currently reading these pages:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/windows/desktop/aa380599(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3sk7e6b.aspx

And I can't say I'm getting any smarter from it, heh. Would you mind giving me an example on how a .rc file would look like?

Comment: http://puu.sh/8tzAk.png This is how I have it right now, gives me an error telling me that cube0.png wasn't found. Error RC2135: file not found: Resource Files\sprites\cube0.png

Comment: the path is relative to the project directory

Comment: Ah, cheers man. Now it works! :)
Thank's for taking your time, I appreciate it a lot, but I need to ask one more thing. How about compiling the resources? I'm reading here that you can put resources in DLL's, but also make an .obj out of .res files?

Comment: Compiling: the RC2135 error message was emitted by the resource compiler, so you're already compiling, and embedding (embedding is done just by specifying the compiled resource file, .res, to the ordinary linker, and Visual Studio does that automatically for you). A DLL is mostly the same as an .exe file, they're both PE (Portable Executable) format. Making .obj out of .res files isn't necessary with Microsoft's tools, but I have a vague memory that maybe it was necessary with GNU g++. Not sure. The toolchains differ in fine details of .rc syntax, and in what encodings they accept.

Comment: By the way, by accepting this answer as "the solution" you tell others that it was useful, while by not accepting it you implicitly tell others, e.g. googlers who end up here, that it wasn't useful. :-)

Comment: I flagged flagged your post as useful, I think.

Sorry for being a bit dense here, the C++ workspace is entierly new to me and I would move the conversation to chat as the site suggests but I don't have enough points it says.

The way it works now is that I can debug and it loads the files from the project folder and if I choose to compile I have to move the resource folder to the output dir(denug/release) manually. Couldn't I just move the .res file there instead of the folder and have the .exe load it from that file, or have I gotten this completely wrong?

Comment: after building the executable contains (copies of) the resources, in your case an image. the originals are not needed.